# I want to select the first and last of the active classes in the slick slide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick

I want to select the first one among the active ones of the slick slider.

Even if you want to use nth-child , it is not a choice because of other things.

Let me show you with a picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlAuh.png)

thank you very much....

---

I tried the part you said, but it looks like the following picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNrnX.png)

If you do as you say, the last place you see in the manager window is active, and the flex property should be entered here, but seeing that it doesn't go in, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: More details would be helpful.  Are you looking for a CSS solution?  JS?  What do you want to do with the selection.  My default answer for this would be `.slick-active:first-child` and `.slick-active:last-child`.  You said we can't use nth-child, but I don't know if that includes first-child/last-child.  If this needs to be JS, then we'd like to see some of your code that's generating this list of things, etc etc

Comment: I've already tried it, but there are 6 that have a class called active, and I can't select it.

Comment: Please provide some more details then.  What kind of solution are you looking for?  What have you tried, and why didn't it work?  Can you provide a snippet of a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem?

Comment: I couldn't attach a picture in the comments, so I added an explanation with a picture above.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace class name to match your code.

```js
// first
document.querySelectorAll(".slick-active")[0]

//last
[...document.querySelectorAll(".slick-active")].at(-1)
```

Then you can change CSS if that is the plan.